# Cross navigation between two different Navigation Graph in Android

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

Thanks for paying attention to this question:

Have 2 different navigation graphs:

**First Navigation Graph**: `navigation_dashboard.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentHome"
    android:name="com.example.genu.FragmentHome"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragmentHome_to_fragmentProfile"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentSecond" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentProfile"
    android:name="com.example.genu.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="fragment_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
```

**Second Navigation Graph**: `gallery_navigation.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/myGalleryFragment"
    android:name="com.generationunified.genu.MyGalleryFragment"
    android:label="fragment_my_gallery"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_gallery" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_myGalleryFragment_to_myHistoryFragment"
        app:destination="@id/myHistoryFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/myHistoryFragment"
    android:name="com.generationunified.genu.MyHistoryFragment"
    android:label="fragment_my_history"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_history" />
```

`DashBoardActivity` holds `navigation_dashboard`  and `GalleryActivity` holds `navigation_gallery`

Now, Let's say we are in `HistoryFragment` which belongs to `GalleryActivity` and wants to open the `ProfileFragment` which belongs to `DashBoardActivity`

How to achieve above mentioned navigation? Any help would be really really appreciated....

Please have a look at below diagram for better understanding:

[image]